# From the two approaches I list, which one is better for CMS page management and why?

Tags: content-management-system

Here are the two scenarios:

First one: You have a CMS you log into go to the page manager, select a template, then add a page into the system, edit the page, save it done.

Second one: You sign in, then go to the URL you want to exist but doesn't exist yet but still shows up as a template to enter in stuff. For example, "/articles/article" and since the URLs were mapped to be dynamic, the article template shows up and has the placeholders to edit right there. Different types of pages or templates would be mapped to different URL patterns such as "/product/[product-number]" etc etc.

Is there any security concerns for doing the latter since I like the second one better in terms of programming as there is no management of pages, just authentication then navigating to the desired page. The first one is more structured and is good listing them out or individiual permission settings.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the authentication considerations, I think both approaches are fine. I see them as ultimately accomplishing the same thing through different user experiences. To answer the question, I would paper prototype each, then pull users into a room and perform a quick / informal usability study, giving them tasks such as "create a page with ..." etc. Evaluate which model performed better. You really should answer this question by including the users that will use the system.

Comment: Here is what I did as the free-form approach www.kitgui.com  but I've used several CMS approaches in the past as traditional. I found this one to be the most fluid in terms of using dynamic URLs as the client is able to have a navigation element that remains the same (or global) for the template regardless of URL coming in. The docs were made in KitGUI to give you an idea -> www.kitgui.com/docs . This idea it totally blue sky but I put it together after using it for a year in my own business and finding it super easy to setup stuff. I really need opinions on this from a developer perspective.